# Cut URL by jquery if URL have two part same

Tags: jquery, html

I have this URL :

```
http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx
```

I need it to be :

http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx

How to by jquery.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say whether this is a general purpose problem and what the pattern you're looking for is.  If what you're trying to do is remove duplicates of the first segment of the path, then you can do that like this with regular javascript:

```
var url = "http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx";

var split = url.split("/");
if (split[3] == split[4]) {
    split.splice(3, 1)
}
url = split.join("/");
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5dArW/

If you're trying to remove any path portions that are the same as any other path portion, then you can use this:

```
var url = "http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx";

function removeDups(array, start) {
    var index = {}, val;
    start = start || 0;
    for (var i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
        val = array[i];
        if (val in index) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
        } else {
            index[val] = true;
        }
    }
}

var split = url.split("/");
removeDups(split, 2);
url = split.join("/");
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QchDZ/

If all you want to do is remove multiple path segments of this exact string `"Ifor-williams-tilhengere"` (which one of your comments seems to now indicate), then you can do that like this:

```
function removeDupSegment(url, dupToLookFor) {
    var split = url.split("/");
    var dupCnt = 0;
    for (var i = 2; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i] == dupToLookFor) {
            ++dupCnt;
            if (dupCnt > 1) {
                split.splice(i, 1);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
    return(split.join("/"));
}

var url = "http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx";
url = removeDupSegment(url, "Ifor-williams-tilhengere");
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tk3zk/

Answer (score 4):

I found the following one liner worked for me:

```
var url = 'http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx';
var result = jQuery.unique(url.split('/')).reverse().join('/');
```

Comment: The [doc for jQuery.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) says: `"Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers."`

Comment: @jfriend00 I know, I saw that too, but it appeared to work for me. The documentation might be out of date.

Comment: URL not fixed , it can change. So i need check URL if it have two string "Ifor-williams-tilhengere" , remove one. Result (http://31839.cateno.vn/Ifor-williams-tilhengere/Nullam-vulputate-velit-sed-bibendum-euismod.aspx)

Comment: @minh You might want to update your question to say that you only want to remove that exact string.

Comment: @GregL - It doesn't seem safe to me to use a jQuery function for something it explicitly says it isn't designed for.  It might work now, but obviously it's not guaranteed to continue to work.  Particularly where there's pure javascript ways of doing it that aren't that hard.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair point, sir, and well made. Your solution is indeed superior to mine.